# Вывод массива

Tags: php, парсер, html

Есть код:

```
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('http://press.rzd.ru/news/public/press');
foreach ($html->find('a[class=news_list_cardLink]') as $element)
echo $element->href .'<br>';
```

Сейчас выхлоп такой:

```
ссылка1
ссылка2
ссылка3
```

Как сделать, что выводилось массивом, то есть

```
    Array
(
    [1] => ссылка1
    [2] => ссылка2
    [3] => ссылка3
)
```

Comment: Наверно вместо `echo $element->href .'<br>';` нужно просто указать `$arr[] = $element->href;`

Comment: вылезает 500 ошибка

Comment: УМВР. Загони только этот код в отдельный файлец, (пере)определи перед обходом переменную `$arr = array()`, посмотри что будет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Исправил. Теперь выводит ссылки.

```
  <?php
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('http://press.rzd.ru/news/public/press');

$array_;
$i = 0;

foreach ($html->find('a[class=news_list_cardLink]') as $element)
{
$array_[$i] = $element->href; $i++;
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($array_);
echo "</pre>";

?>
```

Comment: наверно, нужно

    echo htmlspecialchars(print_r($html->find('a[class=news_list_cardLink]'), true));

Comment: исправил. Теперь выводит ссылки.

Comment: Большое спасибо, теперь успею до дедлайна!